# ngClass in host property of component decorator does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I created the following simple example component that adds some attributes and listener to the component DOM element using the host property of the @Component decorator. In my case [ngClass] is has no effect. Does someone know why and how to fix it?

```js
import { Injector, Component } from "angular2/core";
import { NgClass } from "angular2/common";
import { SelectionService } from "../selection-service";

@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    template: `<div>inner template</div>`,
    host: {
        style: "background-color: yellow", // works
        "[ngClass]": "{'selected': isSelected}", // does not work
        "(mouseover)": "mouseOver($event)", // works
        "(mouseleave)": "mouseLeave($event)", // works
    },
    directives: [NgClass],
})
export class MyComponent {
    private isSelected = false;

    constructor(private selectionService: SelectionService) {
        this.selectionService.select$.subscribe((sel: Selection) => {
            this.isSelected = sel; // has no effect on ngClass
        });
    }

    mouseOver($event) {
        console.log("mouseOver works");
    }

    mouseLeave($event) {
        console.log("mouseLeave works");
    }
}
```

I'm using Angular 2.0.0-beta.7.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ngClass` is a directive and can't be used in host bindings. Host bindings only supports

- property `'[propName]':'expr'`
- attribute `'[attr.attrName]':'expr'`
- event `(event)="someFunction(event);otherExpr"`,
- style `[style.width]="booleanExpr"`
- class `[class.className]="booleanExpr"` binding.
- class `[class]="expr"` where `expr` is a string with space separated classes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my specific case of `ngClass` I added `[class.selected]="isSelected"`, which works.

Comment: `ngClass` is mostly required when the class names you want to toggle are dynamic (passed in by a parent or similar) in other cases the available binding expressions work fine.

Comment: Where can I find a detailed explanation about the host property (syntax and usage) ? There is almost nothing in the doc of the API on angular.io.

Comment: I gess it's not well documented because the recommended way is to use decorators `@HostBinding()`, `@HostListener()`. I also don't know more documentation than https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Directive-decorator.html and it's really not much.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two different ways to bind a host element class to a property using the `@HostBinding` decorator:

```js
@HostBinding('class.enabled') private get isEnabled() { // use getter to reflect external value
    return this.selectionService.state.isEnabled;
}
```

```js
@HostBinding('class.selected') private isSelected = false; // setting this add/removes 'selected' class

constructor(private selectionService: SelectionService) {
    this.selectionService.select$.subscribe(isSelected => {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and it's pretty modular:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core'

type Directions = 'vertical' | 'horizontal'

/**
 * A hairline.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'hairline',
  styleUrls: ['./hairline.component.scss'],
  template: '',
})
export class HairlineComponent {
  @Input() direction: Directions = 'horizontal'
  @Input() padding = false

  @HostBinding('class')
  get classes(): Record<string, boolean> {
    return {
      [this.direction]: true,
      padding: this.padding,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This would overwrite other classes