# Conditional styling on host element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that all it does is render , its something like this:

```
@Component({
     selector: 'my-comp',
     host: ???,
     template: `
         <ng-content></ng-content>
     `
})

 export default class MyComp {
   @Input() title: string;
   public isChanged: boolean;
 }
```

The component has a `isChanged` property and I want to apply styling on the host element based on that `isChanged` property. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use the `class` and `style` prefix for this. Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  host: {
    '[class.className]': 'isChanged'
  },
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export default class MyComp {
  @Input() title: string;
  public isChanged: boolean;
}
```

See the Günter's answer for more details:

- [ngClass in host property of component decorator does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753198/ngclass-in-host-property-of-component-decorator-does-not-work)

Comment: Maybe simple '[class.className]': 'isChanged'

Comment: @yurzui: yes you're completely right! It's for attributes that you need to have a null value to remove it ;-) I updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution using @HostBinder

The accepted solution is using the `host` metadata property which goes against the rules of TSLint:

> TSLint:   Use @HostBinding or @HostListener rather than the `host`
> metadata property (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-06-03)

The same can be achieved using [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) instead:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export default class MyComp {
  @Input() title: string;
  public isChanged: boolean;
  @HostBinding('class.className') get className() { return this.isChanged; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do but something like this should suffice where you use `ngAfterViewInit` and `ElementRef`:

```
import {AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-comp',
   host: ???,
   template: `
     <ng-content></ng-content>
   `
})

 export default class MyComp implements AfterViewInit {
   @Input() title: string;
   public isChanged: boolean;

   constructor(private _ref: ElementRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {

     var host = this._ref.nativeElement;

     if (this.isChanged) {
        host.style.width = '200px';
     }
   }
 }
```

If you want to do some checking for `isChanged` every time it changes you could implement `ngDoCheck` instead/as well:

```
ngDoCheck() {

  if (this.isChanged !== this.previousIsChanged) {

    var host = this._ref.nativeElement;

    if (this.isChanged) {
      host.style.width = '200px';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to let your component fire an event that can be catched by the host (and possibly pass some data with it).

To do that you would have an @output property like:

```
@Output() isChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()
```

then in your code you could do:

```
this.isChanged.emit(some value to pass)
```

And catch it like:

```
(isChanged)="doSomething($event)"
```