# How can I style :host element dynamically based on parameter from @Input?

Tags: css, angular

Usually, I can style the very root of my component by using the *:host* pseudo style like this.

```
:host{ border: 1px solid gold; }
```

But how shold I handle if said style is supposed to be set dynamically, based on the parameters passed to *@Input*?

The only way I can think of at the moment is to add an auxilliary DIV and style it like so.

```
<div [ngClass]="styleMeDynamically"> ... </div>
```

Is there a way to apply a style dynamically directly on the host without the injected DIV?

I've found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258650/1525840) but it requires explicitly stating the classes and connecting them to separate inputs. I'd like to get a config object as passed in parameter and bind the styling using *[ngClass]* to retail full flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is,

Create a custom directive that will accept a style object. and inside that directive, you can get the reference of host element and modify its style.

Here is a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-host-styling-demo)

And here is a quick explanation.

Create a directive as which will accept a style object.

```
import {Directive,TemplateRef,ElementRef,OnChanges,SimpleChanges,OnInit,Renderer2,DoCheck,Input} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appSetStyle]"
})
export class SetStyleDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() appSetStyle: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.applyStyles();
  }

  applyStyles(): void {
    if (this.appSetStyle) {
      for (const key in this.appSetStyle) {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.style[key] = this.appSetStyle[key];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use that style object with any html element or any other component in your project.

```
<app-header [appSetStyle]="dynamicStyles"></app-header>
```

If you don't want to make a directive then you can inject the `ElementRef` inside the component itself which you want to style.

**ElementRef** is the what you need to use to get the reference of host.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Probably [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) decorator can help you. It allows to bind any host attribute including `class` and `style`. For example:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
  // you can conditionally add a class to the host element
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('class.large')
  large = false;

  // it's possible to bind a style as well
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('style.border.px')
  borderWidth = 1;

  @Input()
  green = false;

  // and you can use a getter
  @HostBinding('style.border-color')
  get borderColorStyle() {
    return this.green ? 'green' : 'black';
  }
}
```

Since angular 9 it should be possible even to bind a CSS variable, see *Improved CSS class and style binding* section of the 9 version release [article](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-of-angular-now-available-project-ivy-has-arrived-23c97b63cfa3).

```
<div [style.--main-border-color]=" '#CCC' ">
  <p style="border: 1px solid var(--main-border-color)">hi</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How does it compare to the other answer, would you say? Directive feels a bit overkill. On the other hand, it seems more Angularish. What do you think?

Comment: @KonradViltersten In case of the *directive* solution you should pass all styles from the component parent, it's not a good solution in terms of encapsulation. The child component should provide an interface that allows to setup its appearance, but it shouldn't ask the whole styles. In case of *@HostBinding* solution the component asks only parameters of the style, but it doesn't expose the whole style to the parent.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's just that, there are multiple ways of achieving the same behavior. It's up to you to pick one which fits best for your requirements. You can inject `ElementRef` in your component as well if you don't want to create a directive. Which I have already mentioned in my answer as well.

Comment: @HirenParekh Yes you did. There's nothing wrong with any of the answers. While I agree with you that the approach that suits my requirements the best should be picked, the obstacle is that I got uncertain on how to judge how adequate those are. Hence, me asking.