# Apply :host selector in Angular based on input

Tags: angular

I have a component which accepts an input called size, it looks something like this;

```
<app-container [size]="level"></app-container>
```

`level` can be a series of strings, such as `large`, `small` and `medium`. I'd like to apply a `:host` selector within my components stylesheet so if a size input is provided it applies some CSS to it.

I can do this with CSS via the following if I use `class`, but I can't seem to do the same with Angulars input.

```
<app-container class="large"></app-container>
```

```
:host(.large) {
  color: blue
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: this could help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753198/ngclass-in-host-property-of-component-decorator-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without some ugly hacks, but you can achieve similar functionality by wrapping the html in a div.

HTML:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'large': level === 'large'}">
  // Your HTML here
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.large {
  color: blue;
}
```

Edit: Here's the hacky answer if you want it. It only needs a change in the typescript.

```
class YourComponent {
  @Input() level: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.level === 'large') {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'blue';
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lre3ur

Answer (score 0):

```js
// not necessarily a getter, it could just be a variable
@HostBinding('class.large') public get isLarge() {
  return this.size === 'large';
}
```

```scss
:host {
  &.large {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this assume that `large` is applied as a class to the component first? I want the component to apply the class based on if the input is provided or not, whereas this it looks like it's applying based on if class is applied.

Comment: Yes, it's applied depending on `@Input() size`